# Bootstrap: Text overlay on image stuck to the left side

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm rather new to this but I managed to get a caption onto my image surrounded by a black box (how i wanted it), but the black box (which is at 70% width) with the text seems to be glued to the left of the image.

```
        <div class="row">
                    <div class="text-center" style="position: relative">
                        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/84AfU5A.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive center-block" style="border-radius: 25px; ">
                            <div class="caption" style="position: absolute; top: 55%; width:70%; background-color: black; opacity: 0.5">
                      <p style="color: white !important; opacity: 1 !important">“Text Text Text Text</p>
                </div>
         </div>
</div>
```

Apologies if this is a really obvious fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the left css property to your caption div and you should be fine.
In my example below I added left:5%;

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="text-center" style="position: relative">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/84AfU5A.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive center-block" style="border-radius: 25px; ">
    <div class="caption" style="position: absolute; top: 55%; left:5%; width:70%; background-color: black; opacity: 0.5">
      <p style="color: white !important; opacity: 1 !important">“Text Text Text Text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```